# What should be our policy on requests for sources or references?

Tags: discussion

Recently, there were several questions containing requests for sources or references, or what I consider "reading list" questions.

Other sites routinely close such questions. We tend to allow them, at least the better ones.

Should this policy continue? Or should we be at least somewhat demanding as to which questions we allow?

For instance, a request for sources on German logistical difficulties that cost them World War II might be a "broad" question that would be closed on other sites. Bu perhaps a question about how *a lack of trucks* put the Germans at a disadvantage compared to the Russians (who used trucks in operation Bagration) or the Allies in France might be meaningful?

Where do people on this site think we should draw the line?

Comment: [Related question](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/896/are-requests-for-references-appropriate-on-history-stack-exchangerevisited?rq=1) April 2015 and [Related question](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3826/may-i-request-canonical-resources) October 2018

Comment: Please check the list of related questions; we've probably discussed this topic more often than any other.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should "some" requests for resources be "on-topic"?](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2236/should-some-requests-for-resources-be-on-topic)